# Is there a way to throw a custom compilation error if some MsBuild property is set in any project within a solution file?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csproj, sln-file

**Background**
I have created a `Directory.Build.props` in my root repo folder with the following contents:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I need to prevent the usage of C# 8 syntax within our codebase, since it is targeting .Net 4.7.2
The above file sets the `LangVersion` property for each project within the solution.

**The problem**

Our codebase is big. Many projects within one single solution with many programmers working in differents and / or adding new ones, this is not a problem itself but rather the fact that any programmer can override the `LangVersion` within their own `.csproj` file.

I know we can stop those changes in the code review phase or by sending reminders every hour to all the programmers telling them not to use C# 8 for this specific project. But I was wondering if I could just celebrate their boldness by giving them a nice and handsome compiler error.

Maybe with a custom code analizer with Roslyn? Is there any way?

Comment: In the worst case you may add a custom validation build step that checks that none of the (changed?) `.props`/`.csproj` files have LangVersion > 7.3

Comment: Thanks @EugenePodskal, I have already thought that maybe a custom script run in the Pre-build event command line might do the trick.However I would prefer something more neat perhaps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<Project>

    <Target Name="RestrictLangVersion" BeforeTargets="Compile">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <UnsupportedTarget Condition=" '$(MaxSupportedLangVersion)' == '7.3' AND '$(LangVersion)' == '8.0' ">true</UnsupportedTarget>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Error Text="At *YOUR_COMPANY* we discourage the use of C# 8.0 on unsupported targets" Condition=" '$(UnsupportedTarget)' == 'true' " />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

You can pop that in a `Directory.Build.targets` high up in your CI agent and it should do the trick.

You'll need to add the logic for `preview` etc... (as there are other values of `LangVersion` that will result in `8.0`) and some of those will be dependant on the version of `csc`, so I've left out the hard part.

Basically you'll need to replicate the logic here:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/97123b393c3a5a91cc798b329db0d7fc38634784/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/LanguageVersion.cs#L353-L364

bearing in mind that it will change across different versions of `csc`.

Comment: No worries, I am thinking about making a nuget package that does this with the extra smarts I described. As an ex-team-lead, be careful with these sorts of overbearing policies, hopefully this build warning starts some healthy discussion, rather than a hard rule.

Comment: Just added a comment at the end regarding the missing logic.

Comment: I am indeed one of those bold programmers that were making use of C# 8 as soon as it was supported (at least some features) for .net 4.7 in the latest Visual Studio update ☹️. So I am kind of harakiri-myself here...

Comment: I'm also guilty: https://stu.dev/csharp8-doing-unsupported-things/

Comment: Nice article!  I loved this: "So the good news is that you can enable C# 8.0 on other targets, however it is "unsupported" i.e. this is probably not a good idea".